# Eclipse Plugin Development: Context menu on extension point org.eclipse.ui.bindings does not contain New -> Key

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html) and it tells me to "add the extension point "org.eclipse.ui.bindings" and then to "right-click in this extension point, select New→ Key". As you can see in my screenshot there is no 'New --> Key' in the my context menu. 
[image: No 'New --> Key' in the context menu]
So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to simply edit `plugin.xml` as xml file. Then the section for the key bindgins could look for example like this:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        commandId="Test4.commands.sampleCommand"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        sequence="M1+6">
  </key>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 2):

**In your target platform the `org.eclipse.ui.source` plugin is missing**, with the sources and the schema for the `org.eclipse.ui.binding` extension point.

Because of this Eclipse does not know which child elements the extension point has and offers only this *Generic* element. *Open Schema* won't work either and you will not have a validation, e.g. when you name the element `<keys .../>` instead of `<key .../>` you will not get an error.

To fix this, you can install ***Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources*** containing the missing sources and schemas, e.g. from the update site [`http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.16`](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.16) for - assuming you do not use an outdated Eclipse - the current Eclipse version 2020-06 (4.16) via *Help > Install New Software...* (when not using the running platform as target platform and using a target definition file instead, it's `<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.source.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>`)